# Google App Maker not recognizing an email as a group email for app restriction

Tags: google-app-maker, google-groups

I've developed an application on Google App Maker and have been getting troubles on restricting access on to specific users. I know we could restrict users using groups but when I put the group email under the 'Application Access' the icon on the email is of the first letter and not the group icon. This tells me that app maker is not recognizing the email as a group email.

The email used as the owner and deployer of the app created the group as well and was added as its owner to be able to give it permission to view the membership list of the group.

Admin Console screenshot:
[image]

App Maker settings screenshot:
[image]

Thanks for in advance for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, did you try to report it here? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410

Comment: Thanks, found out what the problem was!  :)